# How to query main collection with another collection [Mongoose]

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

If I have 2 collection:

`product` and `category` product have ref on category...

How can query products by category?

I need something like this:

```
Product.find({category.name: "testCat"}, function() {
...
})
```

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/), where you can kinda `join` two collections

```
db.product.aggregate(
{
  $lookup: {
    from: 'category',
    localField: 'categoryRef',
    foreignField: 'catId',
    as: 'category'
  },
  {$unwind: '$category'},
  {$match: {'category.name': "testCat"}}
})
```

Comment: Lookup lookup ^^

Comment: I found way but it dosn't work it will populate each product with all categories...

Comment: $match should match expected values only. Did you remove that criteria?